# Why can't I get the value of storage using async for AuthGuard?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to do a very simple login in my Ionic 4 app. When a user logs in I set a token in storage. This is working.

I'm using an Auth Guard to check against one page in the app, so if the token is set in storage, the user can view the page. Otherwise they are redirected to the login page.

My problem is that I'm completely stuck in async hell; I just can't figure it out. I'm trying to do a simple check: is the token set in storage or not. if yes, return true, if not, return false.

The problem I'm experiencing is that, even after successfully logging in and storing the token, when trying to access the restricted page I'm still redirected to the login page; I'm assuming it's because of not properly using async in my guard.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    authenticated: boolean;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private storage: Storage
    ) {
        this.getToken();
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

        if (this.authenticated) {
            return true;
        }

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }

    async getToken() {
        await this.storage.get('token').then(res => {
            if (res) {
                this.authenticated = true;
            } else {
                this.authenticated = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is you are checking the storage in constructor and when the service is initialised you were logged out, so `this.authenticated` is always `false`. What you should do instead is, do this check every time route is navigated.

Try this code-

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private storage: Storage
  ) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {

    return this.storage.get('token').then(res => {
      if (res) {
        return true;
      }

      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```